# 'SyntaxError: expected expression, got <' from $.getScript

Tags: jquery, plugins, getscript

I want to create a jQuery multilingual plugin. I also want to open the language files containing the "object" inside my plugin function and access its content.

```
$.getScript('lang/' + settings.language + '.js').done(function() {
  console.log('loaded this');
}).fail(function() {
  consoleError('language file does not exist!');
});
```

The above code gives me the following error.

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Can you make a suggestion?

Comment: That error normally indicates that you're loading HTML in the `getScript()` call - usually due to an error page being returned instead of the expected script. Check the actual response in the console

Comment: does your .js file contain a `<script` tag by mistake, perhaps? As mentioned, look at the actual response from the server

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that you are referencing the script incorrectly and the web server is serving a 404 html page.
Change your code like that:

```
        jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: 'lang/' + settings.language + '.js',
                    dataType: "script",
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        consoleError('language file does not exist!');
                    },
                    success:function(){
                        console.log('loaded this');
                    }
                });
```